# Kendoui equivalent to knockout's with?

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I can't find anything that is similar to knockout's "with" binding in kendo.

Essentially I would like to be able to set the context of a particular area of my html so that I don't have to keep referencing child properties of my observable.

From the ko docs.

```
<h1 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
<p data-bind="with: coords">
    Latitude: <span data-bind="text: latitude"> </span>,
    Longitude: <span data-bind="text: longitude"> </span>
</p>
```

Whereas in kendo I'd have to go

```
<h1 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
<p>
    Latitude: <span data-bind="text: coords.latitude"> </span>,
    Longitude: <span data-bind="text: coords.longitude"> </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any direct equivalent of the `with` binding in Kendo.

As a workaround you can use the [`source` binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/source) which is like the simple `template` binding in KO:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
<p data-template="template" data-bind="source: coords">
    <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        Latitude: <span data-bind="text: latitude"> </span>,
        Longitude: <span data-bind="text: longitude"> </span>
    </script>
</p>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be putting the template itself inside the element that references it.

Comment: @Brett do you have any concrete reason why not to do it? Because the official documentation exactly showing this inline template usage at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/source#source-binding-to-non-array-value

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I've been using Kendo for 3 years and either I've been completely unaware they've always had it documented this way, or they updated the documentation since I last referenced that section. I stand corrected.